# AngularJS ng-repeat objects, filtering by objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is possible to iterating over objects and check their property ?

```
{
 Obj1 : { visible : true, value : 2}
 Obj2 : { visible : false, value : 4}
 Obj3 : { visible : true, value : 6}
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul ng-show="data.templates.attachments">
        <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.templates.attachments | filter :       value.visible">{{key}}</li>
</ul>
```

If I would like to show only key it is perfect, but I would like to hide these invisibles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in data | filter: {visible: true}">{{value.value}}</li>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10323/)

**Update:**

Filter by `object` property in `object`

```
// only for one property, for example {a: 1}
myApp.filter('filterByProperty', function () {
  return function(items, field) {
      var result = {},
          key    = Object.keys(field).pop(),
          value  = field[key];

      angular.forEach(items, function(el, index) {
          if (el[key] === value) {
              result[index] = el;
          }
      });

      return result;
  };
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10336/)

Comment: @InnerWorld you can write your own filter like this http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10336/

Comment: I need to understand them little more, but yes - it is what I would have. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Alexander has already answered the question, but if you still want to keep the element for each object in the dom and just want it not to be shown (the visible property in your object makes an impression that it might just not be shown, instead of not being inserted into dom),

then you might do this using `ng-class`
http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/dKjz5/48/